# want to retrieve single user information from Firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have artist information in my table : 
public class Artist {

```
private String artistId;
private String artistName;
private String artistGenere;
private String email;

public Artist() {

}
```

I want to get artist information based on his email address
as like we can write SQL Query.

```
SELECT * FROM artist WHERE email ="ssssss@gmail.com";
```

Which listener should I use? If possible provide code.
    [Firebase database snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLZG4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Artist").orderByChild("email").equalTo("ssssss@gmail.com");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       String names=datas.child("artistName").getValue().toString();
    //get data
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


   }
 });
```

This `orderByChild("email").equalTo("ssssss@gmail.com");` it is like saying where email="ssssss@gmail.com";

Assuming you have the following db:

```
Artist
  artistid
     artistName: name
     email: ssssss@gmail.com
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference artistDB = mDatabase.getReference("artist");

Query query = artistDB.orderByChild("email").equalTo("ssssss@gmail.com");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     Artist artist = dataSnapshot.getValue(Artist.class);
     doWhatever();
   }
});
```